# What is meant by Atomic Spectrum of operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was going through some properties of linear operators. I came across the word "purely atomic spectrum". Can anyone help me in understanding its meaning?

Comment: An atom of the spectrum is an isolated point of the spectrum. if the spectrum is $\mathbb{N}$, for example, then every point is an atom of the spectrum.